# How to disable automatic Date and Number order flipping in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, right-to-left

The following HTML, when displayed in Internet Explorer 7/8/9 displays the date as:

2011/31/05

In other modern browsers, it displays as:

05/31/2011

The data is generated/stored by a database, so we can't easily modify it. We'd rather also not do browser detection to try to "fix" the issue. It's clear IE is doing this intentionally, however, we'd like to disable the feature somehow as it's not consistent with other browsers. Microsoft Word apparently does something very similar with RTF documents with the same data. So, it's not a "bug" per se, but we'd still like to avoid it and show the date as we embedded it. It also does this for numbers such as 1/2.

When I remove the hex entity: ف preceding the date, the behavior stops. But the text could be a date embedded in an Arabic sentence, so we'd rather it not "auto flip" the dates, potentially causing serious misunderstanding when reloaded later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="right" dir="rtl">
        <span dir="rtl">        
            <span style=" font-size:12pt">
                &#1601;&nbsp; 05/31/2011&#1592;
            </span>     
        </span> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `<pre>` to keep the format as-is.

```
<pre>05/31/2011</pre>
```

You'll have to style `pre` in css to match your current fonts and size though.

```
pre {
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit
}
```

Comment: As I said, we'd really like to avoid trying to manipulate the data (like adding new html elements), as the content is produced by a database for multiple client types.

Comment: You can perform this at page-load time using JavaScript. No need to edit the data.

Comment: We don't want to try to interpret the data. We want to display it as the either the database emitted it or as the user entered it. We really just want IE to stop doing whatever it's doing. :)

Comment: Writing to Microsoft. Maybe in 15 years, they'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the date in a span and specify the direction:

```
&#1601;&nbsp; <span dir="ltr">05/31/2011</span>&#1592;
```

Comment: As I said, we'd really like to avoid trying to manipulate the data (like adding new html elements), as the content is produced by a database for multiple client types.